# Looping across the column in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have table like:

```
Name  Stages               Year  Units
P1    Under Construction   2015   10
P2    Completed            2016   20
P3    Under Construction   2015   30
P4    Completed            2016   40
P5    Under Construction   2016   50
```

My output should look like in a way:

```
Stages               2015  2016
Under Construction    40    50
Completed              0    60
```

I tried queries like:

```
select sum(units) from table_1 where
stages = 'Under Construction' and year = 2016 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select stages, 
       sum(case when year = 2015 then units else 0 end) from units_2015,
       sum(case when year = 2016 then units else 0 end) from units_2016
from t
group by stages;
```

Comment: what if i want to calculate total for both the year for each stage ??